# how to extract page name from complex URL

Tags: javascript

let's say we have this:

`http://www.domainname.com/somepage.php?c=innerContent`

How to retrieve with jQuery only the page name: `somepage.php`

thx

Comment: Couldn't you just search for the text between the final `/` and the first `?`?

Comment: @jsvk That's what I'm trying to do.... tried with .split() but with no results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.domainname.com/somepage.php?c=innerContent";
var temp = url.split("?")[0].split("/");
var pageName = temp[temp.length - 1];
```

Comment: thanks for the tip! Accomplished it using: `var getName = $(location).attr('href').split("?")[0].split("/").slice(-1);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.pathname`. This will give you a leading `/` but that can be easily stripped out. More information is available on MDN for the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) object.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you simply need `location.pathname.substring(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

**window location**

```
var xlastPart = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()
```

**A Link**

```
var lastPart = jQuery("a:eq(3)").attr("pathname").split("/").pop()
```