# Why can I only run 1 JavaScript internal function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to extract the page name from a complex url. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883544/how-to-extract-page-name-from-complex-url) is how I am attempting to do this. Now I am able to get the url of the page but once I try to do anything with it it fails. I am using this in a SharePoint page.

```
//WORKS!
var url = window.location;
alert(url);

//ALERTS NOTHING 
//PREVENTS ALL JAVASCRIPT AFTER THIS FROM RUNNING AS WELL
var url = window.location;
var url_parts = url.split(‘/’);
var main_url = url_parts[0];
alert(main_url);
```

Comment: Make sure you use real single or double quotes. `url.split("/")` or `url.split('/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location` is not a string, it's a `Location` object and it has no method `split`.  It does have a lot of methods for getting parts of the URL, though, that you may want to look at that may even do what you're trying to do:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

If all else fails, you can use `.toString().split`...

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I used window.location.pathname and will now find a way to suck the page name out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just me or is everyone completely missing the point that `‘` and `’` are NOT valid JavaScript quotes?

Use `'` or `"` instead.

And access `location.href` instead of just `location`. That'll help too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window.location.href instead. window.location is an object not a string.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: Please don't link to W3Schools, but MDC or an other, better reference site.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are properties of `window.location` called `host` or `hostname`: `window.location.host` or `window.location.hostname`. You should try them.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is currently single threaded as such the alert will block the execution thread until ok is hit then it should continue, htnl5 is introducing web workers which is kind of cool, but limited ...

back to to your problem you probably want to do this.

```
window.location.href.split("/")
```

or

```
window.location.pathname.split("/")
```

depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Good point, but take a look at his title, and comment in his code.

Comment: I had looked at the title and the code, but I assumed they meant JavaScript execution stopped. In this case, it was likely caused by an uncaught exception. It is unlikely that the problem was that `alert` is synchronous.

Comment: good catch! '\' was probably halting the interpreter completely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the alert methodology.

What I mean is-- it is very difficult to determine from the code snippet, and with alerts, where the fail point is.

There is another way, however, that makes problems like this crystal clear; and that is my recommendation; it is the JavaScript Step-Debugger.

In Chrome or FireFox it is possible to step through your lines of code and inspect the values of each line to determine if it is what you expect or not.

Instructions for Step-Debugging in Chrome: 
1. add the debugger keyword like so, and comment out your alerts:

```
//WORKS!
debugger;
var url = window.location;
//alert(url);

- This will instruct the debugger to pause runtime execution, so that we can see how each line executes.
```

1. With Chrome on your web page, right click on screen and select 'Inspect Element'.

   - This will open up Dev Tools so that the debugger will stop.
2. Refresh page, invoke any event that may be required to execute code.

   - Code execution should pause at your debugger line.
3. Now what you can do is really powerful. Click step-over button, will take you line by line.

   - Now you can hover over variables to see what there state is.
4. My suspicion is that the url.split() is probably erroneous in some way.

   - I took a look and what I am seeing is an error:
         "url has no method split"
   - This makes sense because the object returned was not a String but a Location.
5. So what I did was to look at the members of Location:
         host, hostname, href, origin, pathname...
6. I think you need to split one of those, depending on your needs.

   - For example:

     var url = window.location

     var url_parts = url.href.split('/');

     //url_parts of this post is
     //["http:", "", "stackoverflow.com", "questions", "10987267", "why-can-i-only-run-1-javascript-internal-function"]

Hope that helps.
All the best!
Nash

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
extracturl = function()
{
    url1 = location.href;
    url2 = url1.split('.');
    url3 = url2[0].replace(/http:\/\//gi,'');
    return url3;
}
```

It worked for me.
It takes something like "http://example.com/" and returns "example." (without the quotes and the period.)

Comment: Why not start with `location.hostname`?